# In this case, how enable the event handler in a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a user control that got an image, two textblock, button & integer (in the code class non UI). I have bind this control to the DB and add it in a list with no issues.

But the only thing that is left is. I would like whenever I press the button it pulls the number from the integer in the control and compare that number with the DB and return a result.

Please advise me since I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Sounds like you want to subscribe to Click event of a button.

Answer (score -1):

A good place to start will be http://wpftutorial.net/ where you can lear a lot about WPF and MVVM.
Some good key words for you to search and learn in google will be:
MVVM
WPF Binding
WPF Command
MVVM light

These keywords will give you a good start on learning more WPF

In relation to your question above you need to:
1. handle the button click
2. do something
3. place the result in the required textblock

```
<Button click="some_method_name"/>

public void some_method_name()
{
    // do something
    textBlock.Text = result;
}
```

Comment: -1 That is *not* the appropriate method signature of a `Click` event handler. You cannot use any old method.